# Ascent for projective modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ be commutative rings such that: $(1)$ $B$ is a projective $A$-module $(2)$ $C$ is a finitely presented $B$-module and $(3)$ $C$ is a flat $A$-module.

**Does it follow that $C$ is a projective $A$-module??**

Intuitively this kind of scenario might occur when we mange to "normalize" a flat finitely presented algebra, in which case the question asks if the projectiveness of the normalization would imply the projectiveness of the original algebra.

Recall that a module is projective iff it is Mittag-Leffler, flat, and it decomposes as a direct sum of countably generated modules.  So the meat of the question is whether the hypotheses are enough to transfer the property of being Mittag-Leffler as an $A$-module from $B$ to $C$.

Being Mittag-Leffler is, as far as I know, not a transitive property.
On the other hand, being finitely presented is a transitive property, so in case $B$ is finitely generated the conclusion is immediately yes.

Comment: What about $A=\mathbb Z$, $B=\mathbb Z[T]$ and $C=B\times\mathbb Z[1/p]$ where $B\to C$ is induced by $T\mapsto(T,1/p)$?

Comment: @Z. M Yes that does the job.  "Normalizing" in this case basically knocks out the localization component, which is precisely the obstruction to being projective

Comment: @Z.M Can you think of a counterexample with $C$ faithfully flat over $A$?

Comment: Just take $C=C_0\times B$ where $C_0$ is any counterexample.

Comment: I think that my example is already faithfully flat (it is surjective on Spec)? Anyway, I think that maybe you are interested in an example when $C$ is a domain (that seems more challenging)?

Comment: @Z.M You are of course right, your example is faithfully flat.  You are also right that I was looking for domains, but I didn't say that in my question, which is my own fault!  Your comment was enough to convince me that I don't care very much about this question, which is good enough.